# Restore databases in SQL Server without creating orphaned users

Tags: backup, database, sql-server, ownership

I have seen this in just about every version of SQL Server and blog posts about it seem to treat it as something that occurs sporadically, but since I always seem to encounter this problem, up and until SQL Server 2017, it is now time to find out what I'm doing wrong.

### Scenario:

- A database with a SQL Server (not AD) user
- Backup (i.e. to a file), then restore on different computer or database server
- The user will now appear for that database, but cannot be used, and cannot be added to Logins (because it will complain it already exists):

  [image]
- Deleting that user will throw: 
  The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped.

### Then:

- It is not possible to remove that ownership:

  [image]
- Giving another user ownership does not alleviate this problem

There are several solutions (this [one](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mdegre/2010/12/19/the-database-principal-owns-a-schema-in-the-database-and-cannot-be-dropped/), or this [one](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2620/steps-to-drop-an-orphan-sql-server-user-when-it-owns-a-schema-or-role/)) to fix this after-the-fact, but I would like to fix this at the root:

1. Can I backup the database without its users?
2. Can I restore a database without its users?
3. Can I backup/restore a database *with* its users (they are sql users, so they should be exportable)?
4. Anything else, i.e., can I somehow create the logins for the alienated users, or what else am I doing fundamentally wrong?

I do most of my actions with the SQL Server Management Console, which may not be wise, but I gladly learn a better technique than the tools that are supposed to do this for us.

### MS Documentation is false

This ought to be a no-brainer, [according to Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/copy-databases-with-backup-and-restore):

> *When a database is restored on another computer, the SQL Server login or Microsoft Windows user who initiates the restore operation becomes the owner of the new database automatically. When the database is restored, the system administrator or the new database owner can change database ownership.*

All of this appears to be fundamentally not true, as the above scenario sketches.

Disclaimer: I searched, but wouldn't be surprised if this is a duplicate.

PS: basically, the frustration being, usually you restore in cases of emergency. Spending hours "fixing" what shouldn't be broken is very annoying. Not impossible, not unfixable, just a nuisance.

PPS: running `SELECT name FROM  sys.schemas WHERE principal_id = USER_ID('TeamcityUsr')` for the example above returns the empty set. So the user that was copied-with is really alienated.

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, this is the way it works when restoring a database to another server. If you don't have the logins to match the users then you are left with orphaned users. Have a script ready to run when you restore a db to fix this. [Fixing orphaned database users](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBAdmin/fixing-orphaned-database-users/) [How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-hk/help/918992/how-to-transfer-logins-and-passwords-between-instances-of-sql-server)